# cached_network_image is not loading image

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So I am using latest version of cached_network_image that is cached_network_image: ^2.3.3. But its not loading the image. I have also tried old versions of this library but they did not work too. It was working a day ago. Than I have migrated the project to androidX and after this it did not work. I am not sure if migration has created any issue. My code is:

```
return ClipOval(
  child: Container(
    height: size,
    width: size,
    child: url == null || url == ''
        ? Image.asset(
            'assets/images/user_holder.png',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )
        : CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
            placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
          ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed this by removing flutter_facebook_login package from my pubspec yaml file. I dont why this happened.